# Python Flask App building social network

Tags: python, flask

I am currently learning Python and trying to create a social network.  I am not able to view other streams of people who have made posts on the wall.  I get the following error `AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'models'`.

app.py

```
@app.route('/stream')
@app.route('/stream/<username>')
def stream(username=None):
    template = 'stream.html'
    if username and username != current_user.username:
        try:
            user = models.User.select().where(models.User.username**username).get()


        except models.DoesNotExist:
            abort(404)
        else:
            stream = user.posts.limit(100)


    else:
        user = current_user
        stream = current_user.models.get_stream().limit(100)


    if username != username:
        template = 'user_stream.html'

    return render_template(template, stream=stream, user=user)
```

model.py

```
class User(UserMixin, Model):
    username = CharField(unique=True)
    email = CharField(unique=True)
    password = CharField(max_length=100)
    joined_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    is_admin = BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE
        order_by = ('-joined_at',)

        def get_posts(self):
            return Post.select().where(Post.user == self)

        def get_stream(self):
            return Post.select().where(
                (Post.user << self.following()) |
                (Post.user == self)
            )

        def following(self):
            """The users we are following"""
            return (
                User.select().join(
                    Releationship, on=Releationship.to_user
                ).where(
                    Releationship.from_user == self
                )
            )
        def followers(self):
            """get users following"""
            return (
                User.select().join(
                    Releationship, on=Releationship.from_user
                ).where(
                    Releationship.to_user == self
                )
            )


    @classmethod
    def create_user(cls, username, email, password, admin=False):
        try:
            cls.create(
                username=username,
                email=email,
                password=generate_password_hash(password),
                is_admin=admin
            )

        except IntegrityError:
            raise ValueError("user already exists")

class Post(Model):
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    user = ForeignKeyField(
        rel_model=User,
        related_name='posts'

    )
    content = TextField()

    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE
        order_by = ('-timestamp',)

class Releationship(Model):
    from_user = ForeignKeyField(User, related_name='relationships')
    to_user = ForeignKeyField(User, related_name='related_to')

    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE
        indexes = (
            (('from_user', 'to_user'), True)

        )
```

stream.html

```
{%  extends "stream.html" %}

{%  block content %}

<div class="row">
    <div class="grid-25">
        <h1>{{ user.username }}</h1>
    </div>

<div class="grid-50">

    <div class="grid-33">
        <h5>Posts</h5>
        <p>{{ user.posts }}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-33">

        <h5>Followers</h5>
    <p>{{ user.followers }}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-33">
        <h5>Following</h5>
        <p>{{ user.following }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-25">
       {%  if current_user.is_authenticated() %}
        {%  if user != current_user %}
        {%  if not user in current_user.following() %}
            <a href="{{ url_for('follow', username=user.username) }}" class="small">Follow</a>
            {% else %}
            <a href="{{ url_for('unfollow', username=user.username) }}" class="small">UnFollow</a>
        {%  endif %}
    {%  endif %}
    {%  endif %}

    </div>

</div></div>

{{ super() }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a problem with indentation. Your `get_posts`, `get_stream`, `following` and `followers` methods belong to the `User` class not the `Meta` subclass. Right now you're putting them inside of the `Meta` subclass. Indent them to the same level as the `Meta` subclass.

```
class User(UserMixin, Model):
    username = CharField(unique=True)
    email = CharField(unique=True)
    password = CharField(max_length=100)
    joined_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    is_admin = BooleanField(default=False)



    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE
        order_by = ('-joined_at', )

    def get_posts(self):
        return Post.select().where(Post.user == self)

    def get_stream(self):
        return Post.select().where(
            (Post.user << self.following()) |
            (Post.user == self)
        )

    def following(self):
        """ The users we are following """
        return (
            User.select().join(
                Relationship, on=Relationship.to_user
            ).where(
                Relationship.from_user == self
            )
        )

    def followers(self):
        """ get users following """
        return (
            User.select().join(
                Relationship, on =Relationship.from_user
            ).where(
                Relationship.to_user == self
            )
        )


    @classmethod
    def create_user(cls, username, email, password, admin=False):
        try:
            with DATABASE.transaction():
                cls.create(
                    username=username,
                    email=email,
                    password=generate_password_hash(password),
                    is_admin=admin)
        except IntegrityError:
            raise ValueError("user already exists")
```